# Simple Inverse Kinematics for a slider?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, constraints, inverse-kinematics

I tried recreating something like this:

[image: Made by Flavio Carvalho]

https://www.instagram.com/p/Bk1tq1DgMRV/?taken-by=flvio.cc

The head can move on the x and y axis.

The model itself is done, but I just want to move the head in both directions and have the "arm" move along automatically, and I would like to have them constrained.
I didn't find a tutorial that explains this. I never really worked with bones and constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Tell me if this is ok for you:

- Create 2 objects: Your cube and your cylinder
- Create 1 armature with a small vertical bone for the cube and a long horizontal bone for the cylinder.
- Parent the small cube to the long with a *ctrl P* > *Keep Offset*.
- In Pose mode, give a *Bone Constraint* > *Limit Location* to each bone, choose *Local Space* and click every axis that should be limited.
- Now when you move your cylinder bone it should only go up, and the cube bone should follow it and be constrained in its axis

[image]